# Update `.bashrc` and reload

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, alias

I have a script that inserts some lines to the bottom of my `.bashrc`, is there a way to source the `.bashrc` from within the script so that these changes remain once the script has finished? Here's an MWE of a similar script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "export MyDir='MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

When the script has been run, neither `MyDir` nor `llA` are available unless the `.bashrc` file is sourced manually

Comment: Where is your script placed?

Comment: In the `~` directory, sorry, I'll change the `.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Look at `bash -x ~/.bashrc` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.

Your script is running in a separate process from your interactive shell. Any changes the script's shell makes to the environment will disappear when that shell exits. **A child process is not allowed to alter the environment of the parent.**

Things you can do:

- the script updates your .bashrc and does nothing else: you source your bashrc if the script completes successfully

  ```bsh
  bash yourScript.bash && source .bashrc
  ```
- the script updates .bashrc, and *prints* the source command: make sure it prints nothing else. Then you `eval` the execution of the script.

  ```bsh
  eval "$(bash yourScript.bash)"
  ```
- the script updates the .bashrc and *also* prints what it does. You eval it: this is the script

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash
  exec > >(tee -a "$HOME/.bashrc")

  echo "export MyDir='MyAnalysis'"
  echo "alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'"
  ```

  and you run it like

  ```bsh
  eval "$(bash yourScript.bash)"
  ```
- don't update the *parent* shell, but launch a new interactive shell that will read the bashrc

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash
  {
      echo "export MyDir='MyAnalysis'"
      echo "alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'"
  } >> ~/.bashrc
  exec bash -i
  ```

  The parent shell is not updated.

---

If you make the .bashrc-updating code a *function*, it will work as expected because functions run in the current shell (by default):

```bsh
addMyAnalysis() {
    echo "export MyDir='MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc
    echo "alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc
}
```

---

An alternate technique: create a "conf" directory `$HOME/.bash.d`. Write bash file in there

```bsh
# this is "~/.bash.d/some_file.bash"
export MyDir='MyAnalysis'
alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'
```

And your .bashrc sources any bash file in that directory:

```bsh
if [[ -d ~/.bash.d ]]; then
    shopt -s nullglob
    for f in ~/.bash.d/*.bash; do
        source "$f"
    done
    shopt -u nullglob
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @glenn-jackman, your sourcing happens in a subshell where your script is executed, and at the end of your script you return to the parent shell where no sourcing happened and also .bashrc is not executed anew  - this separation of parent and subshell stems from general security considerations.

What you are looking for is `exec bash`, but not inside your script, but grouped with it, i.e.

```
bash your-script.sh && exec bash
```

This behaves *as if* you would source and then stay in that shell where you sourced. Indeed it *replaces* the current shell with a new shell, and this new shell starts, as every (interactive) shell, with running your .bashrc, now with your changes, and so does every new shell / terminal you start.

Note that ff you would "exec bash" in your script, it would replace the subshell where your script runs, but still being a subshell.

If your goal is a dynamic and temporary manipulation of .bashrc, you should consider @glenn-jackman's suggestions for doing your changes in separate files that can easily be deleted at any point of your choice. For that you could also just have a permanent line

```
[ -f ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons ] && source ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons
```

at the end of your .bashrc and then do (! only *one* ">" in the first line to have a fresh file)

```
echo "" > ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons
echo "export MyDir='MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons
echo "alias llA='ll MyAnalysis'" >> ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons
```

and, at a point of your choice, just

```
rm ~/.bashrc-temporary-addons
```

(Because of the "-f" test there will be no error if "~/.bashrc-temporary-addons" does not exist).

If your .bashrc manipulations should live as long as your session, i.e. until logout (but not reappear at next login), then you could create a `.bash_logout` file to erase temporary files in in "bash.d/" or all contents of "bash.d/", or "~/.bashrc-temporary-addons".